# Is there anything that can be used to hardcode the POC ( highest bar ) for fixed range volume profile for either 6 or 12 hours ( documents ref?)

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5, tradingview-api

I use fixed range volume profile on the 15 minute chart, for the past 6 hours, to determine trades on my 1 minute chart.

I have been wanting to hardcode the 6 hour point of control for a while, for backtesting, as it has to be redone every 6 hours, is there any way to do this from pinecode?